# Mean and variance for multivariate truncated normal

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution, truncated-normal-distribution

Does anyone have a reference for mean and variance of a multivariate normal truncated along a single axis? I.e. $\mathbb{E}[X | x_i > 0]$ and $Var[X | x_i > 0]$, where $X= [x_1,..,x_n] \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163172 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/385423 answer the question about the mean. The variance question was asked but not answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/330771.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/504245/ (closed) has a list of links to answers to closely related questions. The full distribution (not just mean and variance) is obtained for an equivalent question (with slightly different formulation) at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/444925.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Tallis](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2983860) explored this problem in 1961, in the publication *The Moment Generating Function of the Truncated Multi-normal Distribution*, published in the Journal of the Royal Statistical Society.

Later, in 1989, [Leppard & Tallis](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2347752) published *Evaluation of the mean and covariance of the truncated multinormal* in Applied Statistics (38:543–553, 1989).

In 2012, [Manjunath & Wilhelm](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.5387.pdf) published *Moments Calculation For the Doubly Truncated Multivariate Normal Density*, which expanded on Tallis's work which focused on single-axis truncation.

If you are in University, you likely have access to these publications via your library's subscription to JSTOR, Wiley, or other databases.

Check the R package `tmvtnorm` if you are interested in modeling. [Link here](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2010-1/RJournal_2010-1_Wilhelm+Manjunath.pdf).

Comment: This is just wonderfully helpful - many thanks for taking the time.